# getchar_unlocked( ) VS scanf() VS cin

Tags: c++, scanf

What is the difference among  these three input functions in programming language.
Do they input in different ways from each other?

`1.getchar_unlocked()`

```
 #define getcx getchar_unlocked

 inline void inp( int &n ) 
 {
    n=0;
    int ch=getcx();int sign=1;
    while( ch < '0' || ch > '9' ){if(ch=='-')sign=-1; ch=getcx();}

    while(  ch >= '0' && ch <= '9' )
            n = (n<<3)+(n<<1) + ch-'0', ch=getcx();
    n=n*sign;
  }
```

`2.scanf("%d",&n)`

`3.cin>>n`

Which one takes least  time when input the integers?

I use THese header files in c++ where all 3 cased run in c++;

```
  #include<iostream>
  #include<vector>
  #include<set>
  #include<map>
  #include<queue>
  #include<stack>
  #include<string>
  #include<algorithm>
  #include<functional>
  #include<iomanip>
  #include<cstdio>
  #include<cmath>
  #include<cstring>
  #include<cstdlib>
  #include<cassert>
```

Comment: When programming in C++, you want to use `cin`. Hard to give a good answer to the question since you supplied both C and C++ tags. Which one are you using? They're not the same language.

Comment: Removed the `c` tag since `cin` doesn't exist in C.

Answer (score 29):

Two points to consider.

1. `getchar_unlocked` is deprecated in Windows because it is thread unsafe version of `getchar()`.
2. Unless speed factor is too much necessary, try to avoid `getchar_unlocked`.

Now, as far as speed is concerned.

```
    getchar_unlocked > getchar
```

because there is no input stream lock check in `getchar_unlocked` which makes it unsafe.

```
    getchar > scanf
```

because `getchar` reads a single character of input which is char type whereas scanf can read most of the primitive types available in c.

```
    scanf > cin (>> operator)
```

because check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1042110/using-scanf-in-c-programs-is-faster-than-using-cin)

So, finally

```
getchar_unlocked > getchar > scanf > cin
```

Comment: I dont get this comparison : **getchar_unlocked > getchar > scanf > cin**, because except `cin` (which is an object), all others are functions. Comparing functions speed makes sense. However, how can you compare functions with an object? It doesn't even make sense. You can however compare these functions with various functions `cin` support such as `operator>>` overloads and `read()` which have different tradeoffs, e.g `read()` is faster than `operator>>` but it doesn't format the buffer.

Comment: @Nawaz the answer is with the context of question where it clearly states the comparison is between the functions.

Comment: You're not comparing functions, is what I'm saying.

Comment: Just to clarify. All the above comparison are between reading functions available. Althrough I didn't exclusively mentioned operator>> function available in cin object.

Comment: If you've not mentioned it, then your post is misleading.

Answer (score 4):

I had a problem in codechef that had to input many integers abd found out that the char_unlocked() is faster than scanf which is faster than cin

Comment: One problem which explictly states that "Dataset is huge, use faster I/O methods.": [http://uva.onlinejudge.org/external/124/12440.html](http://uva.onlinejudge.org/external/124/12440.html)