# Fast input output function

Tags: c++, c, coding-style, operating-system

```
#define getcx getchar_unlocked
inline void inp( int &n )//fast input function
{
   n=0;
   int ch=getcx();int sign=1;
   while( ch < '0' || ch > '9' ){if(ch=='-')sign=-1; ch=getcx();}

   while(  ch >= '0' && ch <= '9' )
           n = (n<<3)+(n<<1) + ch-'0', ch=getcx();
   n=n*sign;
}
```

Hi I have been using the above function for input in various coding contests but was never able to understand why is it fast. I know the logic but don't know the concept of it's fastness. For example what  is this line doing "#define getcx getchar_unlocked" . Also I don't know any fast output function so is there any fast output function also

Comment: Here's another SO question about this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9052757/getchar-unlocked-vs-scanf-vs-cin

Comment: As the name of the function suggests it's not thread safe, a thread safe input function using a synchronization mechanism can have a significant performance overhead vs. this one.

Comment: Judging by the horribly icky code formatting, I'm guessing it was faster to write than a properly written function... hence it is 'fast'.

Answer (score 3):

The `#define` uses the preprocessor to make `getcx` be a short-hand for the function `getchar_unlocked()`, which is a non-locking character-reading function.

It's a bit awesome that you've competed in several coding contests without understanding this pretty basic piece of C.

The manual page I linked to above mentions `putc_unlocked()` which sounds like pretty much the same thing but for output.

Answer (score 3):

[`getchar_unlocked()`](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl3_getchar_unlocked.htm) is the thread *unsafe* version of `getchar()`The reason that `getchar_unlocked()` *seems* faster is that it doesn't check for any locks on the input stream from where it is supposed to fetch a character. So if another thread has locked the input stream, this thread is [supposed to wait till lock count has come to zero](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl3_flockfile.htm). But this function doesn't care about it, thereby destroying synchronisation between threads.

But if you are sure that lack of synchronisation wont harm you, then this function might help you to be a bit faster.

Also, its [advised](http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/6.5.0/index.jsp?topic=/com.qnx.doc.neutrino_lib_ref/g/getchar_unlocked.html) that you can use it safely only when the invoking thread has locked stdin using [flockfile()](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl3_flockfile.htm) (or `ftrylockfile()`).

Answer (score 2):

Define a macro called `getcx` such that no locks will be used while reading. This is not thread safe but faster if you are not worried about thread safety:

```
#define getcx getchar_unlocked
```

Define `inp` as inline so that it is faster:

```
inline void inp( int &n )//fast input function 
{
   n=0;
   int ch=getcx();int sign=1;
   while( ch < '0' || ch > '9' ){if(ch=='-')sign=-1; ch=getcx();}
```

Multiply n by 10 (using shift to compute 8*n+2*n, which might be faster):

```
   while(  ch >= '0' && ch <= '9' )
           n = (n<<3)+(n<<1) + ch-'0', ch=getcx();
   n=n*sign;
}
```

You can use [putchar_unlocked](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/putchar_unlocked.html) to have a faster output function when thread safety is not an issue.

Comment: "*using shift to compute 8*n+2*n, which is faster*" - which **might be faster**, or might be slower, depending upon your compiler, CPU, optimization, and many other factors.