# using putchar_unlocked for fast output

Tags: c++

I wish to use fast input and output in my code. I understood the use of `getchar_unlocked` for fast input using the below function.

```
inline int next_int() {
    int n = 0;
    char c = getchar_unlocked();
    while (!('0' <= c && c <= '9')) {
        c = getchar_unlocked();
    }
    while ('0' <= c && c <= '9') {
        n = n * 10 + c - '0';
        c = getchar_unlocked();
    }
    return n;
}
```

can someone please explain me how to use fast output using `putchar_unlocked()` function?

I was going through [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12073617/fast-input-output-function) and there someone said `putchar_unlocked()` could be used for fast output.

Comment: are you using c++ or c?

Comment: @aaronman i am using c++

Comment: Then don't do this cause you probably don't need it

Comment: @aaronman i understand the problem i might face but i need to use it to decrease my time in codes i am practising

Comment: Why do you think your code needs to run faster, if you are using c++ you should use the c++ facilities for I/O

Comment: thats because cin and cout are even slower than scanf printf and getchar_unlocked and putchar_unlocked are fastest for input/output...what i need to do is just run my code fast...if its c or c++ doesnt matter to me...thats why i required it..currently the code i have written is in c++ if need be i could chnge it to c

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34661/discussion-between-aaronman-and-tilak-raj-singh)

Answer (score 9):

Well the following code works well for fast output using **putchar_unlocked()**.

```
    #define pc(x) putchar_unlocked(x);
    inline void writeInt (int n)
    {
        int N = n, rev, count = 0;
        rev = N;
        if (N == 0) { pc('0'); pc('\n'); return ;}
        while ((rev % 10) == 0) { count++; rev /= 10;} //obtain the count of the number of 0s
        rev = 0;
        while (N != 0) { rev = (rev<<3) + (rev<<1) + N % 10; N /= 10;}  //store reverse of N in rev
        while (rev != 0) { pc(rev % 10 + '0'); rev /= 10;}
        while (count--) pc('0');
    }
```

Normally Printf is quite fast for outputs,however for writing Integer or Long Outputs,the below function is a tad bit faster.
 Here we use the putchar_unlocked() method for outputting a character which is similar thread-unsafe version of putchar() and is faster.

[See Link.](http://bufferedbyteswriter.blogspot.in/2013/03/fast-inputoutput-in-c.html)

Comment: It checks only if the number have a '0' sequence at the end. This function doesn't work if the number have '0' sequences in the middle. ex.: 12300023

Comment: @648trindade It Works.

Comment: Add the following to the beginning of the function to make it work for negative numbers: `if (n < 0) { pc('-'); n *= -1; }`