# Why is getchar_unlocked() faster in c/c++?

Tags: c++, c, io

I learnt recently that getchar_unlocked() is faster than the normal io operations such as scanf or cin, but what makes it this fast. What does thread unsafe mean in this context?

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16821365/3033711)

Comment: The same thing "thread unsafe" means in any other context.  If you use it it more than one thread, things break.

Answer (score 4):

Comparison of `getchar_unlocked` (or plain `getchar`, for that matter) to `cin` or `scanf` is not an apples-to-apples: `getchar` function grabs a single character from the buffer, and returns it to you, while streams and format-based functions first need to decide what to return by interpreting the current state or the format string, and only then return it to you.

`getchar_unlocked` should be compared to `getchar`. It may indeed be faster if you call it multiple times, e.g. from a tight loop, because it lets you lock and unlock the stream buffer once per loop, rather than once per loop iteration.

In order to read from your input stream safely, you need to lock it before the read. When you call `getchar`, it does this:

- `flockfile(fileptr)`
- `getc_unlocked(fileptr)`
- `funlockfile(fileptr)`

If you call it in a loop ten times, you would see ten calls to `flockfile`, ten calls to `getc_unlocked`, and ten calls to `funlockfile`. If you know that you are reading ten characters, you could call `flockfile` once, make ten calls to `getc_unlocked`, and then call `funlockfile`. This would save you nine calls to each of the flock/funlock functions.

Comment: Perhaps a bigger reason `getchar_unlocked` may be faster than plain `getchar` is that it admits a definition as a macro. The locking requirements of `getchar` basically preclude traditional implementations via a macro. My belief (without any evidence) is that this is the real reason `getchar_unlocked` was added: a desire not to throw away traditional macro-based implementations.