# Optimizing a program C++

Tags: c++, string, optimization

I have to create a program, which counts bursted baloons, like from ZUMA. If I have a line with 3 or more  baloons with the same color this sequence will burst. So in input, I have number of ballons  (3 <= N <= 10^5) , and line with numbers (line with baloons color  (1 <= сi <= 100) ), with 1 sequence for sure. I have to output number of bursted baloons. I have a programm, but it is working longer than 4000msv sometimes. How can I make it working faster?

```
  #include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;


int Fmax(int n, const string& f){
int  max;
vector<int> k(n);

int i, j, p = 0;
for (i = 0; i <= n; i++)
{
    k[i] = 0;
}

for (i = 0; i <= n; i++)
{
    for (j = i; j <= n; j++)
    {

        if (f[i] == f[j])
        {
            k[p]++;

        }
        else break;
    }
    p++;
}

max = k[0];
for (i = 0; i <= p; i++){ if (max <= k[i]){ max = k[i]; } }
return max;
}
string pog(int n){
int d;
string doa;
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++){
    cin >> d;
    doa += (char)d;
}

return doa;
}
void main(){
int i, sc = 1, bf = 1;
string f;
int len;
cin >> i;
f = pog(i);
len = i;

while (Fmax(f.length(), f) >= 3){

    for (int c = 1; c <= f.length(); c++){

        if (f[c] == f[c - 1]){
            if (sc == 1){ bf = c - 1; }
            sc++;
        }
        else{
            if (sc >= 3){ f.erase(bf, sc);  sc = 1; break; }
            sc = 1;
        }



    }
}
cout << len - f.length() << endl;


}
```

Any help is warmly welcome.

Comment: Read [getchar_unlocked( ) VS scanf() VS cin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9052757/getchar-unlocked-vs-scanf-vs-cin)

Comment: `void main` isn't valid C++. Why are you mixing int and char so much?

Comment: **Very important:  Profile.** Use a profile tool or use clock and run for 1E06 iterations; take average.

Answer (score 2):

You are leaking memory. Use vectors to avoid that.

Why do you need to create `array`? Why not use the string directly?

Pass strings which aren't modified by const reference to avoid copies.

Comment: How can i do it? (Pass strings which aren't modified by const reference to avoid copies.)

Comment: @ЮрийГаврилин `int Fmax(int n, const string& f)`

Comment: Kirlk Ok, thanks. And about vectors, i have to use them instead of dynamic arrays?

Comment: @ЮрийГаврилин It is recommended as they are less error prone. Note that their values are set to 0 automatically.

Comment: I changed arrays to vector, and passing strings, and deleted this strange array in Fmax before/. What else can i do?

Comment: The only remaining thing is to see if you can use a more efficient algorithm, but I don't know the answer to that.

Answer (score 0):

Use constant variables for the lengths:

```
const unsigned int f_length = f.length();
while (Fmax(f_length, f) >= 3){

  for (int c = 1; c <= f_length ; c++){
```

This helps the compiler reduce the number of calls to the `length` method.

Comment: I guess i cant Use constant variables for the lengths:, cause length is changing sometimes

Comment: I really doubt this will make any observable difference.