# Parse a C-string of floating numbers

Tags: c++, string, parsing

I have a C-string which contains a list of floating numbers separated by commas and spaces. Each pair of numbers is separated by one (or more) spaces and represents a point where the x and y fields are separated by a comma (and optionally by spaces).

```
" 10,9 2.5, 3   4 ,150.32 "
```

I need to parse this string in order to fill a list of `Point(x, y)`.
Following is my current implementation:

```
const char* strPoints = getString();
std::istringstream sstream(strPoints);

float x, y;
char comma;

while (sstream >> x >> comma >> y)
{
   myList.push(Point(x, y));
}
```

Since I need to parse a lot (up to 500,000) of these strings I'm wondering if there is a **faster** solution.

Comment: This is probably better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: `boost::lexical_cast<float>()` [seems to parse floats several times faster](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast/performance.html) than `stream >>` if you can rule out exceptional data like infinity, NaN, and scientific notation.

Comment: How long does your technique take?  Is it more than a minute?  How much time are you willing to spend optimizing this to save a minute?

Comment: @wallyk A minute?!? It takes about 10 seconds.. too much. I'd like to decrease the time so that it takes 1 second.

Comment: Why is 1 second reasonable and 10 seconds "too much"?  How are you deciding that?

Comment: @wallyk Because you, as user, can wait your application response for about one second, but not much more. The application I'm developing has to render the graphics defined in a xml-based file (SVG).

Comment: "Fast" and "stringstream" don't go together.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at Boost Spirit:

- [How to parse space-separated floats in C++ quickly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17465061/how-to-parse-space-separated-floats-in-c-quickly/17479702#17479702)

It supports NaN, positive and negative infinity just fine. Also it allows you to express the constraining grammar succinctly.

1. ### Simple adaptation of the code

   Here is the adapted sample for your grammar:

   ```
   struct Point { float x,y; };
   typedef std::vector<Point> data_t;

   // And later:
   bool ok = phrase_parse(f,l,*(double_ > ',' > double_), space, data);
   ```

   The iterators can be *any* iterators. So you can hook it up with your C string just fine.

   Here's a straight adaptation of the linked benchmark case. This shows you how to parse from any `std::istream` ***or*** directly from a memory mapped file.

   **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a3df3dd95422f967)</kbd>**

   ---
2. ### Further optimizations (strictly for C strings)

   Here's a version that doesn't need to know the length of the string up front (this is neat because it avoids the `strlen` call in case you didn't have the length available):

   ```
   template <typename OI>
   static inline void parse_points(OI out, char const* it, char const* last = std::numeric_limits<char const*>::max()) {
       namespace qi  = boost::spirit::qi;
       namespace phx = boost::phoenix;

       bool ok = qi::phrase_parse(it, last,
               *(qi::double_ >> ',' >> qi::double_) [ *phx::ref(out) = phx::construct<Point>(qi::_1, qi::_2) ],
               qi::space);

       if (!ok || !(it == last || *it == '\0')) {
           throw it; // TODO proper error reporting?
       }
   }
   ```

   Note how I made it take an ***output iterator*** so that you get to decide how to accumulate the results. The obvious wrapper to /just/ parse to a vector would be:

   ```
   static inline data_t parse_points(char const* szInput) {
       data_t pts;
       parse_points(back_inserter(pts), szInput);
       return pts;
   }
   ```

   But you can also do different things (like append to an existing container, that could have reserved a known capacity up front etc.). Things like this often allow truly optimized integration in the end.

   Here's that code fully demo-ed in ~30 lines of essential code:

   **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5af8bc787bc51805)</kbd>**
3. ### Extra Awesome Bonus

   To show off the flexibility of this parser; if you just wanted to check the input and get a count of the points, you can replace the output iterator with a simple lambda function that increments a counter instead of adds a newly constructed point.

   ```
   int main() {
       int count = 0;
       parse_points( " 10,9 2.5, 3   4 ,150.32    ", boost::make_function_output_iterator([&](Point const&){count++;}));
       std::cout << "elements in sample: " << count << "\n";
   }
   ```

   **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5226f9d0013d206e)</kbd>**

   Since everything is inlined the compiler **[will notice](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/32ac04fb5a40ea61)** that the whole `Point` doesn't need to be constructed here and eliminate that code: **http://paste.ubuntu.com/9781055/**

   > *The main function is seen directly invoking the very parser primitives. Handcoding the parser won't get you better tuning here, at least not without a lot of effort.*

Comment: Nice, I didn't expect Spirit to be that fast.

Comment: @PhilippClaßen To my dismay, I forgot that `qi::rule` does in fact present an erasure point (hence an inlining barrier) to the optimizer. So I simplified my answer a whole lot, and the result is likely a lot faster (as the assembly shows, mostly by being 2x shorter)

Answer (score 3):

I got much better performance parsing out the points using a combination of std::find and std::strtof and the code wasn't much more complicated. Here's the test I ran:

```
#include <iostream>                                                                             
#include <sstream>                                                                              
#include <random>                                                                               
#include <chrono>                                                                               
#include <cctype>                                                                               
#include <algorithm>                                                                            
#include <cstdlib>                                                                              
#include <forward_list>                                                                         

struct Point { float x; float y; };                                                             
using PointList = std::forward_list<Point>;                                                     
using Clock = std::chrono::steady_clock;                                                        
using std::chrono::milliseconds;                                                                

std::string generate_points(int n) {                                                            
  static auto random_generator = std::mt19937{std::random_device{}()};                          
  std::ostringstream oss;                                                                       
  std::uniform_real_distribution<float> distribution(-1, 1);                                    
  for (int i=0; i<n; ++i) {                                                                     
    oss << distribution(random_generator) << " ," << distribution(random_generator) << "\t \n"; 
  }                                                                                             
  return oss.str();                                                                             
}                                                                                               

PointList parse_points1(const char* s) {                                                        
  std::istringstream iss(s);                                                                    
  PointList points;                                                                             
  float x, y;                                                                                   
  char comma;                                                                                   
  while (iss >> x >> comma >> y)                                                                
       points.push_front(Point{x, y});                                                          
  return points;                                                                                
}                                                                                               

inline                                                                                          
std::tuple<Point, const char*> parse_point2(const char* x_first, const char* last) {            
  auto is_whitespace = [](char c) { return std::isspace(c); };                                  
  auto x_last  = std::find(x_first, last, ',');                                                 
  auto y_first = std::find_if_not(std::next(x_last), last, is_whitespace);                      
  auto y_last  = std::find_if(y_first, last, is_whitespace);                                    
  auto x = std::strtof(x_first, (char**)&x_last);                                               
  auto y = std::strtof(y_first, (char**)&y_last);                                               
  auto next_x_first = std::find_if_not(y_last, last, is_whitespace);                            
  return std::make_tuple(Point{x, y}, next_x_first);                                            
}                                                                                               

PointList parse_points2(const char* i, const char* last) {                                      
  PointList points;                                                                             
  Point point;                                                                                  
  while (i != last) {                                                                           
    std::tie(point, i) = parse_point2(i, last);                                                 
    points.push_front(point);                                                                   
  }                                                                                             
  return points;                                                                                
}                                                                                               

int main() {                                                                                    
  auto s = generate_points(500000);                                                             
  auto time0 = Clock::now();                                                                    
  auto points1 = parse_points1(s.c_str());                                                      
  auto time1 = Clock::now();                                                                    
  auto points2 = parse_points2(s.data(), s.data() + s.size());                                  
  auto time2 = Clock::now();                                                                    
  std::cout << "using stringstream: "                                                           
            << std::chrono::duration_cast<milliseconds>(time1 - time0).count() << '\n';         
  std::cout << "using strtof: "                                                                 
            << std::chrono::duration_cast<milliseconds>(time2 - time1).count() << '\n';         
  return 0;                                                                                     
}
```

outputs:

```
using stringstream: 1262
using strtof: 120
```

Comment: Please add white spaces, such as spaces, tabs, newlines during the generation phase.

Comment: The spirit solution [from my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28014785/85371) is faster still. See *[compared live on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bee327c0abf68636)* (even faster with suitably reserved containers instead of using `forward_list`: *[live on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/61d1195f5983e878)*). Also, it supports NaN and ±infinity. (It is also a lot more generic, at the cost of taking a lot longer to compile, I guess).

Comment: @sehe yes your solution is the fastest one, so I accept it as my answer. Anyway I'm able to optimize the mickb solution in order to get an implementation not so much slower than your even without using boost. I think I'l go without boost. +1 to mickb

Answer (score 0):

You can first try to disable the sychronization with the C I/O:

```
std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
```

Source: [Using scanf() in C++ programs is faster than using cin?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12762166/783510)

You can also try to use [alternatives to iostream](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast/performance.html):

- [boost_lexical_cast](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast/examples.html#boost_lexical_cast.examples.strings_to_numbers_conversion) and define BOOST_LEXICAL_CAST_ASSUME_C_LOCALE
- [scanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/)

I think you should give the `sync_with_stdio(false)` a try. The other alternatives require more coding, and I'm not sure that you will win much (if any).

Comment: I do not have any significant speedup by using `std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false)`

Comment: The OP does not mention files at all.

Comment: Instead of reading the whole SVG file into one "const char*" and then parsing it, it should be faster to parse it on the fly.

Comment: @PhilippClaßen where did you get the SVG context from? Anyhoops my answer addresses this too (with a link to benchmarks of `std::istream&` vs. `mmap`)

Comment: @sehe OP mentioned it in a comment to his question. Yes, I also think that parsing directly from istream or mmap would speed things up.

Comment: @PhilippClaßen ah. That comment was hidden so "find in page" didn't reveal it. Thanks