# Unable to read two strings with cin.get()

Tags: c++, iostream

[image: sample execution]Why does trying to input two strings using cin.get() fails? I can successfully read the first string but the input fails for second string and subsequent operations.. See the code:

```c++
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
long int n,k;
char a[11],b[11];
cin.get(a,11);

n = atoi(a);

cin.get(b,11);
cout<<b;   
k = atoi(b);


cout      << "\ncin.rdstate(): " << cin.rdstate()
      << "\n    cin.eof(): " << cin.eof()
      << "\n   cin.fail(): " << cin.fail()
      << "\n    cin.bad(): " << cin.bad()
      << "\n   cin.good(): " << cin.good() << endl << endl;
}
```

I am trying to input two strings and store them into long int variables as shown in program, but the `cin.get(b,11)` fails and stack overflow occurs for
 `k= atoi(b)` .Also, you may observe nothing is output for `cout<<b` .. And, at last `cin.fail()` is set to 1 , which means I am doing some kind of logical error.. Please help me in rectifying this!
Please suggest some method which is fast and meant for c++ only ..
 (If you  feel this question is too bad please mention in comments before down voting this, I am already struggling at 21 rep!)

Comment: have you declared "a" and "b" in your code?

Comment: Can you please show us the input you give?

Comment: ya... i forgot earlier but have declared them now!

Comment: do you still have the same problem? can you post the new code?

Comment: Also, remember that if you enter a newline to terminate the first input, then the newline will *not* be extracted from the input stream. See e.g. [this `get` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg then do I have to use EOF?

Comment: As you are coding in C++, I would recommend using `std::string` rather than C's `char[]`

Comment: I recommend using [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) and [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) instead. And if you have C++11, then [`std::stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) to convert to integer.

Comment: is std::string fast enough?? I have to perform 2.5 Mbs of input and output in 3s .. I am doing this for a competition ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\n will remain in the buffer after the first cin. You can solve this problem by adding an empty cin.get()

```
cin.get(a,11);
n = atoi(a);
cin.get();
cin.get(b,11);
cout<<b;   
k = atoi(b);
```

Answer (score 1):

`cin.get()` Does not extract the delimiter from the input ([documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get)).

If you are C++ with streams it makes sense to use the built in functionality. In particular, C++ offers formatted I/O. To read two numbers you should use:

```
long int a, b;
cin >> a;
cin >> b;
```

This will read two numbers from the standard input.

---

If speed is a concern, try to turn off C I/O synchronisation: `std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);` There is an interesting benchmark [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12762166/1013568) that shows that if you turn of synchronisation with C I/O, streams are actually pretty fast.

Comment: because of being formatted, cin is very slow for high volume operations.. I obviously know cin .. I started c++ with that only!!

Comment: thats superb! I just wanted the c speed in c++ and got it!!