# C++, printf vs cout performance

Tags: c++, printf, cout

I wrote the following program in C++ to measure how much time it will take to print to the default output stream in different ways:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
using namespace std::chrono;

int main() {
// Get starting timepoint
auto start = high_resolution_clock::now();

for (int i=0;i<100000;i++)
{
    cout << "Hello";
}

// Get ending timepoint
auto stop = high_resolution_clock::now();

// Get duration. Substart timepoints to
// get durarion. To cast it to proper unit
// use duration cast method
auto duration = duration_cast<microseconds>(stop - start);

cout << "Time taken by function: "
     << duration.count() << " microseconds" << endl;

return 0;
```

}

At the first round I ran it with: `cout << "Hello" << endl;` and it took 147,570 microseconds.

At the second round I rant it with: `cout << "Hello\n";` and took 128,543 microseconds.

Lastly, I ran it with: `printf("Hello\n");` and it took 121,223 microseconds.

What caused this noticeable difference?

Note: I took the average from 10 tests for each one.

Comment: Also add `ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);` and `cin.tie(NULL);` in the cout case and then compare performance to check if the numbers change.

Comment: What was the variance of the measurements? How many measurements? I other words, how do you know the difference is noticeable?

Comment: I ran 10 test for each one and took the average, in total 30 tests.

Answer (score 1):

By default, cin/cout **waste time synchronizing themselves with the C library’s stdio buffers**, so that you can freely intermix calls to scanf/printf with operations on cin/cout.

Turn this off with

```
std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
```

Also many C++ tutorials tell you to write cout << endl instead of cout << '\n'. But endl is actually slower because it forces a flush, which is usually unnecessary. (You’d need to flush if you were writing, say, an interactive progress bar, but not when writing a million lines of data.) Write '\n' instead of endl.

Also as C++ is object-oriented , **cin and cout are objects and hence the overall time is increased due to object binding**.

So, a simple one liner, "**std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);**" could make cin/cout faster than printf/scanf.
Hope this helps you

Comment: now it's even faster than printf, is that normal? plus could you explain when to use endl? what do you mean by interactive progress bar

Comment: Yes, it is completely normal,   also "cout << “\n”" seems performance wise better than "cout << endl;"  unless flushing of stream is required. So you need to use endl when flushing is required.

Comment: Why cin/cout synchronizing themselves with the C library’s stdio buffers lead to a waste of time ?

Answer (score -3):

Anything in an OOP will be slower than the equivalent in a purely functional language like C. OOP comes with a price for object binding.
internal syncing / flushing in is what normally slows down iostream i/o in this case, Furthur, Actual times also vary from compiler to compiler.

[Using scanf() in C++ programs is faster than using cin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1042110/using-scanf-in-c-programs-is-faster-than-using-cin)

look at this answer for more clarity.

Comment: This is incorrect, it used to be a claim for C over C++ back in the past.

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis I'd like to know more why it's wrong? **endl** does flushing, right?