# Disadvantages of turning off cin synchronization with C scanf

Tags: c++, c, synchronization, scanf, cin

I recently learned something from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1042110/using-scanf-in-c-programs-is-faster-than-using-cin) about `cin` in C++ and its speed was compared with the speed of `scanf` in C. Calling `cin` object is much slower than calling `scanf` function as usual but when I was reading the accepted answer, I understood if we call `std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);`, `cin` synchronization with `scanf` is turned off and `cin` speed becomes so faster and even faster than `scanf` in this case.

So, will we face some problems if we turn it off? If so, what problems, and is it good to turn off `cin` synchronization with `scanf` in C? Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you use both sets of I/O functions (header `<cstdio>` or `<stdio.h>` and also `<iostream>`) on the same stream (e.g. the `stdin` stream is associated with both `scanf` and `cin`), then you'd better leave them synchronized.

If any one stream only uses one I/O family you can turn off synchronization (you can still use `fscanf` with a particular file and `cin` with `stdin` for example, as long as separate streams are involved).

Comment: Is it still necessary to manually turn off synchronization if you don't mix C and C++ I/O? It seems like a weird exception to C++'s "fast by default" philosophy. One would expect performance-pessimizing synchronization to be opt-in.

Comment: @NathanPierson: Backward compatibility is a bigger goal than fast-by-default.  It seems more worthwhile to share buffers in an efficient manner where the synchronization cost goes away, than it does to try to disable synchronization by default.

Comment: @NathanPierson: The primary time you'd want to turn off synchronization is exactly that--when you're not mixing the two at all. Careful use of weak external symbols would probably let you automate unsynchronized access if the program didn't use any C-style I/O at all though.

Comment: @JerryCoffin: That can't work on any system that supports (a) dynamic loading and (b) shared libraries for the C and C++ standard library, because the program can dynamically load a new library that uses the C API at any time, including after iostreams has started buffering data.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Yeah, dealing with that would be tricky, at best. I'd have to think about it bit to be at all sure, but my immediate reaction is that I'm not *entirely* convinced it couldn't be handled as well (but it would definitely take more than what I was contemplating).

Comment: @JerryCoffin: It seems far easier to build a unified buffering layer than stdio and iostreams can share, that supports the union of whatever features (block-get and unget) both use, so that there's no penalty for synchronization.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Could well be.

Answer (score 4):

Basically problem can manifest when C API is used at the same time. Many strange artifacts can appear: missing data, wrong order, unexpected error.

It is possible you have full control over full code stack and you can ensure that C API is not used.

Sadly usually your application uses third party libraries. One of them can use C API to output some data to stream (especially if one of them is C library). Since you do not control third party library behavior, synchronization is required.